# Testing a redux function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, testing, jestjs

I am testing a function like this

```
export default (middlewares) => {
    return createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));
};
```

For this I wrote a mock test using jest

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import createGlobalStore from '../store';

jest.mock('redux');

describe('Store test', () => {
    it('testing create global store', () => {
        const mockTestValue = 1;
        createStore.mockResolvedValue(mockTestValue);
        expect(createGlobalStore([])).toBe(mockTestValue);
    });
});
```

But my code is failing.

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 1
    Received: {}
```

I am not sure if I have written correct test case. Could anybody help me correcting this or writing this test case better way?

Comment: `createGlobalStore([])` is just creating the store (an object) in this case right? Do you mean to access a value on the store to compare it to?

Comment: I am not sure whether that would be a good test or not.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the unit test. The following is a more complete unit test code.

`index.ts`:

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

function rootReducer(state) {
  return state;
}

export default (middlewares) => {
  return createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));
};
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
import createGlobalStore from './';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

jest.mock('redux');

describe('63369776', () => {
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it('should pass', () => {
    const mockTestValue = 1;
    createStore.mockReturnValueOnce(mockTestValue);
    applyMiddleware.mockReturnValueOnce('store enhancer');
    expect(createGlobalStore([])).toBe(mockTestValue);
    expect(createStore).toBeCalledWith(expect.any(Function), 'store enhancer');
    expect(applyMiddleware).toBeCalledWith(...[]);
  });
});
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/63369776/index.test.js (11.603s)
  63369776
    ✓ should pass (7ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |       75 |      100 |       50 |       75 |                   |
 index.js |       75 |      100 |       50 |       75 |                 4 |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.977s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/63369776